# How to "rollback" a remote branch to a specific tag

Tags: git

I have a branch were each deployment is tagged. In case of incident I would like to "rollback" my branch to the previous working tag.

I tried the following without any success.
It feels like I doing something wrong at a very basic level but I don't really understand what.

```
# Checking if the tag is on the branch with
git tag --merged $BRANCH --sort=taggerdate --list

# Trying to rollback with
git push --force origin refs/tags/$PREVIOUS_TAG:refs/heads/$BRANCH
```

The result

```
To https://github.com/me/myrepo
 ! [remote rejected]   my_previous_tag -> my_branch (bad ref)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/me/myrepo'
```

EDIT:
A quick example trying to explain what I am trying to do

I have a branch BRANCH with the following tags on it:

- deployment_1
- deployment_2
- deployment_3

Each pointing to different commits.
I would like to basically bring back my remote branch to

- deployment_1
- deployment_2

and remove all the commits after that. Like I would do with a hard reset.

Comment: I would try to checkout the tag and commit it

Comment: `git push origin "+$TAG:refs/heads/$BRANCH"` is not working?

Comment: @knittl nope same error.

Comment: @Jens you mean checkout or reset to the tag locally and then push?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Likely your tag is an annotated tag (check with `git cat-file -t "$PREVIOUS_TAG"` – it outputs `tag` for annotated tags and `commit` for lightweight tags).
You need to unwrap the commit from it – and you should really include the *full* error message including this important part:

> remote: error: cannot update ref 'refs/heads/my-branch': trying to write non-commit object ... to branch 'refs/heads/my-branch'

Only commits can be pushed to branch refs:

```
git push origin "+$PREVIOUS_TAG^{commit}:refs/heads/$BRANCH"
```

Comment: Sorry about the error. I tried your example and now I just get a "Everything up-to-date". So it doesn't seem to move the branch back to the tag but just push the tag?

Comment: @ITChap everything up-to-date means that the branch already points to the same commit as the tag does. Did you forget to put the `+` there? Then it will also show this message if the branch is ahead of the tag.

Comment: Ok, so, it actually works perfectly. For some reasons  my tags were wrong and all pointed to the same commit. I recreated my tags pointing them to different commits and now it works. Thank you.